# Word to describe the knowledge of certain number of people

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that can explain the specific knowledge that just certain number of people have. For example, when doctors talk, they use specific vocabulary for their field.

> When doctors talk they use their [specific knowledge] which is only understood by them.

Comment: Do you mean knowledge or vocabulary? For vocabulary, use *jargon*. For knowledge, consider *field* or *discipline*. For the body of recorded knowledge, consider *the literature* (the definite article is important in this context).

Comment: You cannot talk about an "amount" of people. Amount is used for uncountable things like sugar. You should use "number" here, as you would for sugar lumps.

Comment: No basic research is shown here.

Comment: Please supply an example sentence. Do you want a stand-alone noun, or will a modifier of 'knowledge' do?

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for is **jargon**.

> "I'm looking for a big word that can explain the specific knowledge
>   that just certain amount of peolpe have. For example, When doctors
>   talk they use an specific vocabulary for their area that doctors
>   dominate."
>
> "When doctors talk they use their **jargon** which is only understood
>   by them."

So, doctors, for example, share a specialized vocabulary -- a **jargon** -- that it is easy for other doctors -- but difficult for non-medical professionals -- to understand.

From *The Free Dictionary*:

> **jargon**: the specialized language of a trade, profession, or similar group, especially when viewed as difficult to understand by
>   outsiders

In general, different types of specialist have their own **jargon**, whether they be medical doctors, physicists, mathematicians, lawyers, etymologists, or grammatologists.

Even within areas such as medicine, physics, etc, practitioners specialize in sub-areas. In physics, for example, a physicist might specialize in condensed matter physics; solid state physics; quantum physics; statistical physics; or atomic, molecular, and optical physics, to mention only several of many possible sub-areas; each of these sub-areas has its own **jargon**. One could easily construct similar lists for medical doctors, mathematicians, lawyers, etymologists, and grammatologists.

Answer (score 2):

There is the adjective *esoteric* which means, something likely known by only a few people, or a specific group of people. However, as Dan Bron commented, an *esoteric vocabulary* would be usually referred to as  *jargon*.

Answer (score 1):

***[terminology](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terminology)*** (M-W):

> the technical or special terms used in a business, art, science, or
>   special subject
>
> Example: the *terminology* favored by sportscasters

***[lingo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lingo)*** (M-W):

> the special vocabulary of a particular field of interest
>
> Example: The book has a lot of computer *lingo* that I don't understand.

***[parlance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parlance)*** (M-W):

> language used by a particular group of people

Answer (score 0):

If a phrase will work instead of only one "big word", then perhaps *domain expertise* or *subject matter expertise* will work in your case. They're phrases in common use and can apply to different domains/disciplines broadly, not just medicine. [See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert)

Also, these terms describe the specific knowledge and not the people themselves (e.g. subject matter experts). And while *jargon* refers to the terms these *subject matter experts* often use, the phrase mentioned in this post refers to the knowledge that those jargon terms are often used to describe.

Answer (score 0):

**lexicon**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107781?redirectedFrom=lexicon#eid)

> fig.  the vocabulary proper to some department of knowledge or sphere
>   of activity

As in:

> 1973   Times 31 July    He [Mr. Ehrlichman] said the term ‘deep
>   six’—meaning throw in the river—had not been ‘part of my **lexicon**’.

and

> When doctors talk they use their medical **lexicon,** which is only understood by
>   them.

Answer (score 0):

Esoteric - Intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialised knowledge or interest. The opposite of this word is exoteric, which means intended for or likely to be understood by the general public.

Credentials: Musa Phungula studied Master of Commerce in Business Management Strategy-as-Practice

Comment: _esoteric_ was already given as an answer...

Answer (score -1):

**Expertise**:

> special skill or knowledge : the skill or knowledge an expert has - [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expertise)

Answer (score -1):

Pansophism: It also has to do more specifically with pedagogic ideas of universal wisdom (pansophia), as it occurred in the educational system of universal knowledge.

Oligosophism: Has to do more specifically with pedagogical ideas, as it happens in the educational system of knowledge for few people (oligosophia).

Comment: Jairo, are these real words or did you make them up? If they're real, please [edit] your answer to include a published definition of each, linked to the source, so that we can judge whether the words suit the purpose of the question. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)